# Recommend workflow with GIT before publish apps to Google Play

Tags: android, git

Is it any recommendation about the workflow before build the signed APK?

At now, I have a project work with eclipse and TortoiseGIT.

My work space on  **"C:\GoodApp"**

Every times i publish to Google Play, i have to clone the repo to

**"C:\GoodApp_Release"**

And open the project by eclipse and clean up the project follow this guide.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html

Finally, export the signed APK.

So is it better way to do with only one repo **"C:\GoodApp"**?
I heard some terms of SVN : release branch or something like that.
Does GIT exist this feature?

I see a item named "Create Branch" on TortoiseGIT and i can select base on head "MASTER",
It seems this is what i want.

But is it every time i have to create new branch when release new version?

Comment: Why don't you use tags?

Comment: @DonL. I see the git book, it said GIT tags just a marker?

Comment: yeah, but thats enough, isn't it? You have a release version, tag it with "release version 1.2". build it and load it to google play. later you can always check out again from that commit.

Comment: @DonL.Thanks you for comment. However, i have to do some pre-release jobs, like remove the Log() method, Debug attribute in XML before build the APK, so that the source code may have to changed.

Comment: okay, you might then want to create a new branch for each release